# How to extract text from file and add it into an ArrayList?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, automation

I am creating a QCM app, so i want to get questions and answers from a text file like [this one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F2RgPRw0w6FC6PscDPpkem0S12OTYJlj) and get the question and the answers then add it all to an array like this:

```
var myQstList: Array<String> = arrayOf("")
myQstList = arrayOf(
                    "myQestion1",
                    "myQestion2",
                    "myQestion3",
                    "myQestion4"
                    )

var myAns: Array<String> = arrayOf("")
myAns= arrayOf(
                    "myOption1",
                    "myOption2",
                    "myOption3",
                    "myOption4"
                    )
```

> I want to do the same for each question and it answers please see the
> [doc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1F2RgPRw0w6FC6PscDPpkem0S12OTYJlj) to understand my situation well.
>
> **NOTE:** i'm using kotlin on my android app.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is convert the content of the text file to Json document it would be easier and cleaner to map a Json document directly to object. for example:

```
{
[
{
"question1":["answer1","answer2","answer3"]
},
{
"question2":["answer1","answer2","answer3"]
}
]
}
```

Ok let's start with the implementation step by step.

add Gson to your project using:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Here is the sample object that the json will be mapped to:

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Question {

@SerializedName("questionModel")
@Expose
private List<QuestionModel> questionModel = null;

public List<QuestionModel> getQuestionModel() {
return questionModel;
}

public void setQuestionModel(List<QuestionModel> questionModel) {
this.questionModel = questionModel;
}

}
```

save this in another File called QuestionModel.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class QuestionModel {

@SerializedName("question")
@Expose
private String question;
@SerializedName("answers")
@Expose
private List<String> answers = null;

public String getQuestion() {
return question;
}

public void setQuestion(String question) {
this.question = question;
}

public List<String> getAnswers() {
return answers;
}

public void setAnswers(List<String> answers) {
this.answers = answers;
}

}
```

Here is also a sample Json for your question

```
  {
  "questionModel":[
    {
"question" : "This is a sample question",
"answers" : ["answer1","answer2","answer3"]
}
  ]

}
```

You can save the json in a file called 'sample.json' in the assets folder, read the content and parse to the object with the code below:

```
String jsonSring = null;
try {
InputStream is = getAssets().open("data/sample.json");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
jsonString = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
} catch (IOException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

Gson gson = new Gson();
Question questionObject = gson.fromJson(jsonSring, Question.class);
```

So there you have it, the json file which has all your questions have been mapped to the Question Object which has a definition for the list of all QuestionModel.

As u can see, each QuestionModel has a question and list of possible answers.

Comment: my problem is how to extract the question and the option then add it to an ArrayList

Comment: well, if u agree to use this method that I suggested then I can write code to do the extraction.

Comment: yes of curse and i'll confirm your answer if it work

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can read in each line of the file in kotlin.  My example just prints out each line.  Replace that with whatever you want to do with each.  For example add them to an array.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val inputStream: InputStream = File("yourfile.txt").inputStream()
  val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()

  inputStream.bufferedReader().useLines { lines -> lines.forEach { lineList.add(it)} }

  lineList.forEach{println(">  " + it)}

}
```

Comment: if you see in the doc above, you will see that the question is followed by an empty line then five lines of options...please can you edit your code to make it more efficacy for this case